# How to seed a model (using the seed-fu gem) that has been translated using the globalize3 gem (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seed, globalize3

In a Ruby on Rails app, how would one seed a model (using the seed-fu gem) that has been translated using the globalize3 gem?

I tried seeding both the table and translated table with the code below, but it didn't work.

fixtures:

**products.rb**

```
 Product.seed(:id,
   { :id => 1 }
 )
```

**product_translation.rb**

```
 Product_translation.seed(:id,
   { :id => 1, :product_id => 1, :locale => "en", :name => "foo"},
   { :id => 2, :product_id => 1, :locale => "ja", :name => "bar"}
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used seed-fu, but I know globalize3 fairly well and `Product_translation` doesn't look right to me. Shouldn't it be `Product::Translation` (or `Product.translation_class`)?

Maybe this would work:

**product_translations.rb**

```
Product::Translation.seed(:id,
  { :id => 1, :product_id => 1, :locale => "en", :name => "foo"},
  { :id => 2, :product_id => 1, :locale => "en", :name => "bar"}
)
```